# How to get all the persistent properties of a grails Domain Class along with their constraints in a single Collection?

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I need to get all the information about a particular Grails domain class, i.e. the persistent properties and the constraints related to them in a single collection. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following with get you a map with the property name as key and a map of constraints as values, works in Grails 3:

```
def d = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(MyDomain.class)

def pp = d.persistentProperties.collectEntries {
    [it.name, d.constrainedProperties[it.name]?.appliedConstraints ]
}
```

Comment: This helped me, but is there a way to find out current property is allowed to be nullable or not? I have given constraint in the domain. I tried but didn't get proper values for constraint and its value. I want to get constraint and it value

Answer (score 8):

As of grails 3.3, the accepted answer is no longer correct.  `DefaultGrailsDomainClass` is now deprecated and the single argument constructor will throw an Exception that mappingContext is not yet initialized.

Inject the `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` bean and get the `PersistentEntity` with

```
def persistentEntity = grailsDomainClassMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(MyDomain.class.name)
def propertyList = persistentEntity.getPersistentProperties()
```

Comment: The class `GrailsDomainClassMappingContext` seems to be obsolete by now. The class `HibernateMappingContext` worked in my setup.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like this is deprecated in GORM 6.1 (or earlier)...  probably a cleaner way than injecting a specific context is to get it from `grailsApplication.mappingContext`...  abstract it a level further

Answer (score 2):

I use this solution on Grails 3.3.9:

1) autowire this propoerty

```
MappingContext grailsDomainClassMappingContext
```

2) retrieve `propertyList` and `constrainedProperties`

```
ConstrainedDiscovery constrainedDiscovery = GrailsFactoriesLoader.loadFactory(ConstrainedDiscovery.class);
PersistentEntity crlPe = grailsDomainClassMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(MyDomain.name)

def propertyList = persistentEntity.getPersistentProperties()
Map constrainedProperties = constrainedDiscovery.findConstrainedProperties(crlPe);
```

---

Furthermore the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) states you should be able to retrieve constraints by calling this:

```
MyDomain.constrainedProperties
```

It indeed works but with an annoying warning in the log. This solution may be easily used with the log message suppressed by:

```
logger("org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsDomainClass", ERROR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Grails 4.x

```
def persistentEntity = grailsApplication.mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(object.getClass().getName())
```

Answer (score 1):

For Grails 4

```scala
List<PersistentProperty> props = Holders
                .grailsApplication
                .mappingContext
                .getPersistentEntity(object.class.name)
                .persistentProperties
```